# pip install on specific project rather than globaly

Tags: python, pip, bower

I got used to bower which has an option -g for installing packages globally, while not stating that -g will cause bower to install package within the project.

Now, I'm back to Python and looking to do the same with a package I needed.
When I use pip install, the package is installed at the

> C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\

directory although I need that package specifically for a project I'm working on.
I need to modify a lot of the package so I prefer to have it modified within the project.

My question is, how can I install a package directly to my project rather than to my python site-packages using pip?

Comment: For this you have virtual environments. Please read the guide at http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ !

Comment: @KlausD. You won't believe how much I fear using virtualenv. The thought of dozens, even hundreds of virtual environments left abandoned, neither alive nor dead, makes me sick :P Seriously, is there a way to do so without virtualenv?

Comment: Being abandoned is not a feature of virtual environments, but of their owner. If somebody provides a different solution, how do you plan to avoid abandoning the environments you set up?

Comment: @tripleee I don't plan to avoid abandoning the non-virtual environments, but in a counter intuitive way, I feel better going by them everyday rather than forget about them. Maybe because I believe that one day I'll "clean my room" and will have everything on sight.

Comment: @tripleee OK enough with avoiding the virtual env, I'll go for it. Leaving this question open to see if there's a solution not including virtual env.

Comment: You could just move the package manually inside your project. I have a similar fear of virtual env.